# Outlook API Filter by Subject line only returns 275 results

Tags: outlook-restapi

We have been having issues with the Outlook Mail API for a while now. There was a known bug where filtering by subject line would not return results and it was fixed.

We tried our implementation again, but are capped at 275 results every time. Below is an example of the code/query that we are running and you can see that the first 2 pages have nextLink for the next page but the third page stops at 75 results with no nextLink. We tested this on multiple accounts (all with 30,000+ emails) and different subject line queries and get 275 results every time.

```
search emails that contain 'a' in the subject
Request 1
{
  "$select": "ReceivedDateTime",
  "$search": "\"subject:(a)\"",
  "$top": 100
}

Response
result.value.length: 100
result.@odata.nextLink: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/MailFolders/Inbox/Messages/?%24select=ReceivedDateTime&%24search=%22subject%3a(a)%22&%24top=100&%24skiptoken=MSZZVlF3ZWsxNmJHMU5hbEY1V2xNd2VFOVVWVFZNVkZFMVQxZFZkRmxVUW0xTlV6RnNXWHByZWs1RVNtbFpNa2t5V1dwQmJXTjZNSGhOUkVFOQ%3d%3d -- this is the token for retrieveing the next page
```

---

```
Request 2
{
  "$select": "ReceivedDateTime",
  "$search": "\"subject:(a)\"",
  "$top": "100",
  "$skiptoken": "MSZZVlF3ZWsxNmJHMU5hbEY1V2xNd2VFOVVWVFZNVkZFMVQxZFZkRmxVUW0xTlV6RnNXWHByZWs1RVNtbFpNa2t5V1dwQmJXTjZNSGhOUkVFOQ=="
}

Response
result.value.length: 100
result.@odata.nextLink: 
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/MailFolders/Inbox/Messages/?%24select=ReceivedDateTime&%24search=%22subject%3a(a)%22&%24top=100&%24skiptoken=MSZZVlF3ZWsxNmJHMU5hbEY1V2xNd2VFOVVWVFZNVkZFMVQxZFZkRmxVUW0xTlV6RnNXWHByZWs1RVNtbFpNa2t5V1dwQmJXTjZNSGxOUkVFOQ%3d%3d
```

---

```
Request 3
{
  "$select": "ReceivedDateTime",
  "$search": "\"subject:(a)\"",
  "$top": "100",
  "$skiptoken": "MSZZVlF3ZWsxNmJHMU5hbEY1V2xNd2VFOVVWVFZNVkZFMVQxZFZkRmxVUW0xTlV6RnNXWHByZWs1RVNtbFpNa2t5V1dwQmJXTjZNSGxOUkVFOQ=="
}

Response
result.value.length: 75
result.@odata.nextLink: undefined  -- no next page
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue/is there a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The search component for the mailboxes is capping results at a lower level. You'll notice that you get similar results if you search with OWA's search bar, for example. The search team is taking feedback on this for consideration in future planning, so I encourage you to leave feedback on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). I've logged a work item to revisit this cap, but I can't make any promises :)

Comment: Is there anyway to search by subject and get all results?

Comment: The cap comes into play when you use `$search`. If you can get the same results using `$filter` you can bypass that cap. Of course `$filter` doesn't have all the same "fuzzy" search characteristics, but depending on what kind of searches you're doing, it may be an option.

Comment: We're running into the same issue here and it's frustrating. We can rewrite our "received>date" searches using $filter but our users care about "recipients,participants,to,cc" searches and there is way to use $filter to mimic those.